# Exposing python application as a web application

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-applications

I have a very simple python 3.5 script that is a conversation between user and machine. I haven't used any server in this and have used sqlite3 database.
Now I want to expose this application as a web application but don't know how to proceed regarding this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Google is your friend here. Try `turn python into web app` or something similar.  A very good module to look into is Flask

Comment: @Nelson Thank You :)